# JDBC-ODBC Bridge Removed in Java 8, what is the best alternative?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

Seeing as Oracle has removed the JDBC-ODBC Bridge driver in the latest release of Java (version 8), is there a good alternative that will enable us developers to access ODBC databases in Java 8?

Oracle is apparently recommending that we use vendor-specific JDBC drivers instead of the Bridge, which tells me that Microsoft should have its own JDBC driver for connecting to MS Access databases in Java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html

I'm currently looking into whether or not Microsoft has this technology available, but in the meantime, does anyone know if they do or if another alternative is available?

Comment: You can use jdbc odbc classes from jre7 also in jre8 - see stackoverflow.com/a/34617075/2110961

Comment: ...just keep in mind you will have no UTF-8 support: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6345277

Answer (score 2):

> does anyone know if ... another alternative is available [for Access]?

Yes. [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is a viable alternative. For more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Comment: Third-party, enterprise-grade, commercial JDBC-to-ODBC Bridges also exist, including those [from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/).

Comment: UCanAccess on the other hand is free/open-source. Just gave it a try, and it works great. Basically, it's just a really good JDBC driver which supports MS Access.