# 64 Bit Machine with 32 Bit JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, x86, jvm, 64-bit

I would like to connect via ODBC to my 32 Bit Access database with my 64 Bit machine.
I read several solutions on Internet and one of them is to use a 32 Bit JVM.

I have installed the latest 32 Bit JVM and set my Eclipse correctly, I would like to know if I did it correctly because I am still not able to connect to my database.

Here are the steps I have done :
- Download & Install the latest JDK : jdk-8u31-windows-i586.exe
- Set my Eclipse settings > Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE > Add > C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31
- Select the 32Bit JRE
- Run my program

The displayed error is :
Unable to load the JDBC driver sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
ERROR database.DatabaseConnection - Please check your CLASSPATH
No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:DataBase

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751071/jdbc-odbc-bridge-removed-in-java-8-what-is-the-best-alternative and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Comment: You seem to be missing a library jar file at runtime.